# No method error in users controller // undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make users on my site able to view other users' cars that they have uploaded.  On the homepage where a user views their own cars, I did this by rendering `shared/feed` that holds a user's cars.  Doing this gives me no error, but when I render `shared/feed` to show cars on another user's page, I get `undefined method 'any?' for nil:NilClass` on the second line in `shared/feed`

**shared/feed**

```
<div id="car_feed">
    <% if @feed_items.any? %>
      <ul class="cars">
        <%= render @feed_items %>
      </ul>
    <% else %>
      <h3> You haven't added any cars yet.</h3>
      <h3> Add one in the sidebar!</h3>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

On the home page, this works fine.

**home.html.erb**

```
<% if logged_in? %>
<div>
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <div>
      <h1>My Profile</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-unit user_info">
      <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
    </div>
    <section class="hero-unit car_form">
      <%= render 'shared/car_form' %>
    </section>
  </aside>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h1>My Cars</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
  </div>
</div>

<% else %>
//landing page content
<% end %>
```

but I get the error when rendering a show page

**show.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <%= render 'users/user' %>
</div>
```

**_user.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <div>
      <h1>My Profile</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-unit user_info">
      <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.cars.count, "Car") %></h2>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h1>My Cars</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**cars_controller**

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy, :edit]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:destroy, :edit]

  def create
      @car = current_user.cars.build(cars_params)
      respond_to do |format|
          if @car.save
              @feed_items = current_user.feed
              format.html { redirect_to root_url }
              format.js
          else
              format.html { render 'static_pages/home' }
              format.js
          end
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @car.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Car deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  def edit
    @car.edit
    flash[:success] = "Car edited"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def cars_params
      params.require(:car).permit(:year, :brand, :model, :vin, :mileage, :picture)
    end

    def correct_user
      @car = current_user.cars.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @car.nil?
    end
end
```

**users_controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        log_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Thank you for signing up, welcome to ensage!"
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
      else
          render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def destroy
      User.find(params[:id]).destroy
      flash[:success] = "User deleted"
      redirect_to users_url
    end

    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

**staticpages_controller**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    if logged_in?
      @car = current_user.cars.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end

  def shop_home
    if shop_logged_in?
      @shop = current_shop
    end
  end

  def help
  end

  def about 
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong, you are checking whether if `@feed_items` is empty or not by `#any?`. We use `#any?` to check condition on attributes of a definite object by passing a block. `nil.any?` will raise exception since it's a method of enumerable. You can simply check presence of `@feed_items` by `if @feed_items` .

Comment: I removed .any? and now the logic skips `if @feed_items` and shows the `<% else %>` part, even though there are items in the feed. Is this what you mean me to do?

Comment: Could you raise your @feed_items collection, `raise @feed_items.inspect` and tell me what it shows?

Comment: Where are you initialising `@feed_items` ?

Comment: I guess you have a `home` action in your controller? Paste that controller too.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed home and feed_items initialization are both in the static pages controller, I added it above.

Comment: Add `@feed_items` initialization in users_controller show action too.

Comment: THAT was the missing piece thank you.

Comment: there is a nice way to say thank you in stack overflow! And did you see my updated answer, which was updated 12 hours ago? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `@feed_items` collection is `nil` and calling `#any?` on `nil` will raise `NoMethodError`.

If there is a single valid element, `any?` will return true, if all the elements are nil, it will return false, and raise exception if the object itself is `nil`

```
[nil, "car", nil].any?
#=> true

[nil, nil, nil].any?
#=> false

[].any?
#=> false

nil.any?
#=> NoMethodError:
```

You need to pass `@feed_items` as locals when you are rending `user` partial:

```
<%= render 'users/user', locals: {feed_items: @feed_items} %>
                                              ^ instance variable declared in show action
```

Then in your user partial you are rendering `feed` partial, you need pass `feed_items` again:

```
<%= render 'shared/feed', locals: {feed_items: feed_items} %>
                                               ^ not the instance variable
```

You feed will look like this:

```
<div id="car_feed">
  <% if feed_items %>
    <ul class="cars">
      <%= render feed_items %>
    </ul>
  <% else %>
    <h3> You haven't added any cars yet.</h3>
    <h3> Add one in the sidebar!</h3>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Your show action in users controller need to be like this, if you want to see the feed items of that particular user:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @feed_items = @user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your controller I can't confirm that you're declaring the @feed_items variable to your #show controller like it looks like you are for your #index method.

If you've left that out, then @feed_items doesn't exist which is why calling .any? on a nil variable isn't working.

***update***
Reviewing your last static controller:

```
def home
    if logged_in?
      @car = current_user.cars.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
```

Is why it works for home. Users/show controller needs something like:

```
  def show
    #don't forget to put whatever other pertinent code goes in this controller
    if logged_in?
      @feed_items = a_user_you_selected.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added my users controller above because it's the one raising the error with the `show` method, and the cars controller because its the only one that mentions @feed.  Do you see any issues?

Comment: That helps, but I'm still super confused how you've set this up. The problem is your Users/show method doesn't reference @feed_items. Sharvy has posted some very helpful ideas on how to get around that.

Comment: a_user_you_selected is @user as defined in the controller.  thanks.